# Android Google+ log-in flow glitch

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity, google-plus

Hi I'm trying to implement a simple google+ login activity on android. This is my Main Activity class. I have a simple Activity layout with 3 buttons. One Google+ sign in button, one logout button and one revoke_access button. When I run the app for the first time on my device, I get logged-in, and the sign-in button disappears. But when I tap the BACK button on my device and exit the app, and then tap on the app icon again, the app loads, and for about 1 second, I can still see the Google+ sign-in button, and then it disappears. I was wondering what would be the best way to avoid the user from seeing this button in the first place. The Google+ sign in button should not be visible at all if the user is already logged on, even for a split second. Thanks.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

/* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

/* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/*
 * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
 * from starting further intents.
 */
private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private boolean mSignInClicked;
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_logout).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access).setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // The intent was canceled before it was sent. Return to the
            // default
            // state and attempt to connect to get an updated
            // ConnectionResult.
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the
        // user clicks
        // 'sign-in'.
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // We've resolved any connection errors. mGoogleApiClient can be used to
    // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.

    mSignInClicked = false;
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.sign_in_button:
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
        break;

    case R.id.btn_logout:
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        break;

    case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
            this.onStart();
        }
        break;
    }
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

}